# Explain what is meant by this code

Tags: groovy

I have found the line

```
[compileJava, compileTestJava, javadoc]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

in a gradle snippet located http://snippbin.com/XMql2MXd.

I am curious how to interpret what this line is actually doing.

Comment: Though this question does seem that it was a waist, I truly wasn't sure about how to even search for the operator that is mentioned in the answer i accepted.  As without knowing that such an operator exists how would one search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a Groovy question.  You can read about the **spread operator** in [Groovy operators](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator%28*.%29) for more information.

To "simplify" this a bit, this is doing the following assignments:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
javadoc.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

And `options` is short here for `getOptions()` and `encoding='UTF-8'` is short for `setEncoding('UTF-8')`.  The spread operator in the original code gathers all options from the provided list into a new list of options and then the next spread operator calls the setter on each element.